# Module not found under wsgi setup but works fine with Werkzeug server

Tags: python, flask, centos, mod-wsgi, wsgi

My dir Structure:

```html
├── app
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   └── js
│   └── templates
│       ├── graphs
│       ├── layout
│       └── login_and_home
├── auth
    └── views.py
```

I am deplying a Flask app with that structure, I have my .wsgi file and seems to working but it cannot find module auth.views

here is my wsgi file

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/example')

from app import app as application
```

Here is my httpd configs:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName example.co

WSGIDaemonProcess example python-path=/var/www/example:/var/www/example/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages user=apache group=apache threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example/deploy.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/example>
    WSGIProcessGroup example
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Not sure why auth.views cannot be found.

Comment: At a guess, your mod_wsgi is actually compiled for Python 2.7, not 3.4 as your virtual environment is. Under Python 2.7, package directories must have ``__init__.py`` files, but you don't have them, so likely can't import submodule in package. Use checks in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html to work out what Python version mod_wsgi is compiled for.

Comment: Also read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for how to configure mod_wsgi for a Python virtual environment correctly. You are not using the recommended method.